# Setting class for BODY in index.html programmatically in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pretty standard `React` app.

Up until now, I had set a class for my `<body>` tag in the `index.html` that rendered a nice background that looked like this:

`<body class="bg-123">`.

Now, I'd like to set the class for the `<body>` tag programmatically based on URL.

Specifically, if the current URL is `http OR https://{host}/public`, I want to set the class to

`<body class="bg-public">`.

This should work in production as well as locally while I'm developing the app. So the URL could be:

`http://localhost:3000/public`
or the actual production URL `https://myapp.com/public`.

I'd appreciate some pointers on this. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you messing with classes in your index.html rather than dealing with this inside a component?

Comment: It's not React way what you are trying to do. inside your app assign a div that will style bg

Comment: Yup! That seems to be the case. I'll have to mess with some `CSS` so that I can avoid the global `class` set at the `<body>` tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer your question, you can access the body using `document.body` and access its classes using `document.body.classList`, so you could use that to do something like `document.body.classList.toggle("some-class")`. And you can access the current url using `window.location.href` or in this case it might work better to use `location.pathname`.

But a better answer would be that this kind of scripting is pretty anti-pattern for React. The more React-y solution would be something like having a class on your main component that you change based on a state. Something like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { backgroundClass: "bg-123" }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.backgroundClass}>...</div>
    );
  }
  // This would be whatever event happens in your app that should cause the background to change
  handleSomeEvent() {
    this.setState({
      backgroundClass: "bg-456",
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue I have is that the designer created a global CSS class that is set at the BODY tag level. Then I use your approach throughout the app in my components but I now also set the global tag differently as well. I’m not particularly crazy about handling the CSS for the BODY tag programmatically either!

Comment: @sam, your problem is organizational not with React or CSS.

Comment: @gaditzkhori That's an under-statement :-) This is not the only mess we're cleaning up after this designer! Ultimately, it's my fault for allowing it to happen in the first place.